# Running Normal Dart HTML and Angular Dart 2 in the same app

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is it possible to mix a normal Dart HTML application with Angular Dart 2 and have Angular Dart 2 run in certain parts of the application and not other parts?

I've attempted that, but it seems Angular is injecting itself into every page.

index1.html:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
```

index2.html:

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<script async src="main2.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.dart:

```
// many imports

void main() {
  // manual code to hook urls, html etc
}
```

main2.dart:

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/bootstrap.dart';

@Component(selector: 'my-app', template: '<h1>Testing Angular Dart 2</h1>')
class AppComponent {}
main() {
    bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
...
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  ...
  less_dart: any
  browser: any
  http: any
  event_bus: any
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: any
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.0
transformers:
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
- less_dart:
    entry_points: [web/styles/main.less, web/styles/test.less]
    build_mode: dart
- angular2:
    entry_points: web/main2.dart
```

The angular2 transformer is clearly pointing at `main2.dart` and only `index2.html` is importing `main2.dart`, but when I load `index1.html` which is importing `main.dart`, the angular app runs.

Is it possible to do what I want to do or is it a case of all-or-nothing when including Angular Dart 2?

Comment: How do you figure that "the angular app runs"? Does your `index.html` contain an `<app></app>` tag as well? Is this in Dartium or Crome/Firefix (with `pub serve`) or after `pub build`?

Comment: This happens when doing `pub serve`, I haven't tried with build yet, but need it to work with `pub serve` as well.
When I go to `index1.html`, I see `<h1>Testing Angular Dart 2</h1>`, when I go to `index2.html`, I see the same loading page followed by `<h1>Testing Angular Dart 2</h1>`. `Index1.html` does not contain any special tags such as `<my-app>`, only normal html like `div`, 'p', etc. When I remove the transformer again out of `pubspec`, `index1.html` loads its old html again as it should.

Comment: I see, probably a transformer bug with multiple entry points. I guess it would help to add this information to the issue you created as well.

Comment: I restarted my PC and the problem went away, `index1.html` now serves the right stuff and `index2.html` serves the angular page. Very strange, I didn't make any code changes!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Latest OSX - did a Dart upgrade yesterday to 1.13.1, might be related.

Comment: Could be an inconsistency of files in `.pub` which were regenerated with the new Dart version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "it seems Angular is injecting itself into every page."? If you have different entry points (`index1.html`, `index2.html`, ...) each entry point is an individual application and for each you can enable Angular or not. If this doesn't work it's a bug in some transformer.

Comment: Going to index1.html and index2.html, I'm expecting a non-angular page and an angular page, what I'm seeing however is two angular pages.

Comment: Is this the right place to log a bug for it?
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues?q=is%3Aopen

Comment: Logged one here in the meantime:
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1747

Comment: Going to leave the question here in case somebody else manages to reproduce it, I can't reproduce it anymore after a system restart.